# How to separate an array list into individual letters in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I am working on an assignment that wants me to create a program that accepts a text file with words in it, goes through every word, and then outputs the word with the most amount of double letters. So if a text file had 2 words, (past and progressive for example), it would output progressive. My problem is getting the program to compare each letter in a word. Specifically I cant seem to figure out how to split each word into its letters. Here is what I have so far.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Doubles {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    ///Prompts the user to give a file.
    System.out.println("Enter the location of your file...");
    String location = keyboard.next();
    Scanner file = null;
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    ///If the the file location is wrong, give an error. 
    try {
        file = new Scanner(new File(location));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Error: File not found");
        System.exit(1);
    }


    while(file.hasNext()){
        String word = file.nextLine();
        list.add(word);
    }
    ///System.out.println(list);
    keyboard.close();

    doublefinder(list);

}

private static void doublefinder(List<String> list) {
        ///Code to separate and compare letters.
    }

}
```

I have tried many different approaches but I can't seem to find a solution. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What exactly did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .toCharArray method to create a char array where each element is a letter of the word. 
http://crunchify.com/java-simple-way-to-convert-string-to-char-array/

An example implementation is as follows:

```
 public static boolean isDoubleword(String str){
     char[] letters = str.toCharArray();
     for(int i = 0; i< letters.length-1; i++){
         if(letters[i] == letters[i+1])return true;
     }
     return false;
 }
```

The above function takes a string and returns if the string is a double word.

Answer (score 0):

Arem,

The approach that I would use is to make a method that takes in a string and returns the number of double letters. This can be accomplished using the String.toCharArray(); function. You can then iterate through that array to compare the letters to see how many double letters there are in a string.

e.g.

```
public static int numDoubles(String str) {
    int numDoubles = 0;
    char[] blah = str.toCharArray()
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++ {
        //if the character == nextChar
        numDoubles++;
    }
    return numDoubles;
}
```

Use that return value to compare your strings.

Answer (score 0):

The method could look like that

```
private String doubleFinder(List<String> list){
    int maxDoubleLetters = 0;
    int maxDoubleLettersID = 0; // the position of the word in your list
    for(int n = 0; n < list.size(); n++){ // cycle throught each word
        String word = list.get(n); // get a word from the list
        char[] letters = word.toCharArray(); // split the word into letters
        int doubleLetters = 0;
        for(int i = 1; i < letters.length; i++){ // search for all double letters
            if(letters[i] == letters[i-1]) doubleLetters++;
        }
        if(doubleLetters > maxDoubleLetters){
            maxDoubleLetters = doubleLetters;
            maxDoubleLettersID = n;
        }
    }
    if(maxDoubleLetters > 0)
        return list.get(maxDoubleLetters);
    else
        return null;
}
```

The method shown above will return the word with the highest number of double letters. If the file does not contain any words with double letters the method will return `null`.

Note: This will not work for words containing triple letters.

If you have any more questions fell free to ask in the comment section.